# How to use Material Components for the web with Webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

Rails 5.2.1 webpacker4.0

app/javascript/application.scss

```
@import "material-components-web/material-components-web";
```

I use webpacker with the default setting, but it does not work well.
What additional settings do I need?
I want to use material-components-web in webpacker

err

```
Module build failed:
@import "@material/base/mixins";
File to import not found or unreadable: @material/base/mixins.
```

webpack/environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const vue =  require('./loaders/vue')

environment.plugins.append('VueLoaderPlugin', new VueLoaderPlugin())
environment.loaders.append('vue', vue)
module.exports = environment
```